# C++ Generating a 4 digit random number

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to generate a 4 digit random number in C++

I used the following code

```
#include<time.h>

int number;

number=rand()%1000;
srand ( time(NULL) );
```

but its doesn't gives a total random number

Comment: As a complement to the accepted answer, there is a very nice article concerning the proper usage of rand() and srand() at http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
number = rand() % 9000 + 1000;
```

There are 9000 four-digit numbers, right? Starting from 1000 till 9999. `rand()` will return a random number from 0 to `RAND_MAX`. `rand() % 9000` will be from 0 to 8999 and `rand() % 9000 + 1000;` will be from 1000 to 9999 . In general when you want a random number from a to b inclusive the formula is

```
rand() % (b - a + 1) + a
```

Also note that ***`srand()` should be called only once and before any `rand()`.***

If you *do* consider the numbers between 0 an 999 inclusive to be "four digit numbers", simply use `rand() % 10000` in that case. I don't consider them to be but I'm covering all bases, just in case.

HTH

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP can figure out the first part himself. And by the way the fact that 0045 is not a 4 digits number is arguable. The important point is to call `srand` first in order to get a "total random number".

Comment: +1. And might I also suggest that, if there's even the _slightest_ possibility that this program will run multiple times in a tight loop, insert a `sleep(1)` before `srand(time(0))` so that the seeds will be better selected. This will avoid the inevitable "why aren't my random sequences random?" questions :-)

Answer (score 4):

Remember to call `srand` only once.

Take a look at [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/random), if you don't like the distribution of `rand`.

```
// produces randomness out of thin air
boost::mt19937 rng;

// distribution that maps to 1000..9999
boost::uniform_int<> fourdigits(1000,9999);

// glues randomness with mapping
boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_int<> > die(rng, fourdigits);

// simulate rolling a die
int x = die();
```

Comment: Killing a sparrow with a nuke, are we ? :) Kidding, I like boost, but it just might be too much for the op who seems to be a beginner

Comment: Though to be fair, it's standard in C++0x, so should be a standard way of distributing numbers.

Comment: @GMan: Still whether or not it is standard it is just too complicated for a beginner. My point is it's great we will have it in the standard but maybe it should be kept for intermediate/advanced learners

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: I agree with the nuke thing. But although using Boost.Random require a lot more code, I can see that people find `boost::uniform_int<> fourdigits(1000, 9999)` more logical than `rand() % 9000 + 1000`.

Answer (score 2):

You must seed your random generator `srand` **before** calling `rand()`

```
#include<time.h>

srand( time(NULL) );
int number = rand() % 10000; // number between 0 and 9999
```